# Passing value of labels in prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

Using the prepareforsegue method, I need to pass the value of each label to the next viewcontroller class. I know I should pass the values in each cell as a single object to the next viewcontroller class, however I am not sure the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your next controller, you need to have a variable in the .h file that you can set. Then in `prepareForSeque`, you can do:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NextViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSArray* labels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [cell viewWithTag:1], [cell viewWithTag:2], [cell viewWithTag:3], [cell viewWithTag:4], nil];

        dest.labels = labels;
    }
}
```

Then in your destination controller's `initWithFrame`, you can iterate each label and call: `text`:

```
for (UILabel* label in self.labels)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [label text]);
}
```

Comment: so in my destination viewcontroller, I have 4 uilabels that I would like each value that is passed over to be set too. How would I do that

Comment: Just as shown above. Instead of using a for-loop, set each one manually or instead of creating an array in `prepareForSegue`, set each label from there. IE: `dest.label1 = [[cell viewWithTag:1] text]`

Comment: Cast it to a UILabel then call text.

Comment: how would I go about doing that

Comment: `[((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1]) text]`

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass anything. In prepareforSegue, create a reference of source view controller in DestinationVC (Example below)

```
    [(DestinationVC *)segue.destinationViewController sourceVC] = self;
```

Then in DestinationVC, refer to tableview property of source view controller, run a loop to refer all the cells (example below)

```
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:i]];

   //Refer to all subviews and see if they are UIlabel

   }
```